# Shell script to load multiples CSV files into multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, multiple-file-upload

I am new to pgSQL and Linux platforms. I have 5000+ files that are in a dir and I need to load them into PostgreSQL in different tables.

file name examples:
test 20200415.txt
test 20200416.txt
test 20200417.txt
answer 20200415.txt
answer 20200416.txt
answer 20200417.txt

table name examples:
schema.Test
schema.Answer

1. I need to create a loop that can load all these files into relevant tables, as you can see there is date suffix as part of the file name.
2. I need to strip the date suffix and load it as date value in each relevant table .i.e
   i). the date value in the table schema.Test will be 2020/04/15 when I load "test
   20200415.txt" and date value in the same table will be 020/04/16 when I load "test
   20200416.txt" and so forth.
   ii). I will need to archive a file every time it successfully loads into the database.

NB: I do not have superuser permissions on both OS(linux) and PostgreSQL.
Please assist me, Thank you in Advance

update:

I do not have superuser permissions on both OS(linux) and PostgreSQL.
-CSV format with headers.
-I can delete instead of archiving.

-yes I can connect to the database and I am able to execute,
\copy schema.test (column1, column2, column3)from 'mypath/test
20200415.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER

Comment: This needs more information. The format of the data in the files? The language you are using? Can you connect to the database at all? What privileges do you have? Also these privileges you talk about are they for the OS ans/or the database? Why do you need to archive the files if you are just reading from them?

Comment: I have updated my post. Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Well you are not going to be able to do what you want with ```COPY```. You will need some sort of program that walks over the directory and processes each file. Unless you let us know what language(s) you can use, then this is not going much further.

Comment: can I not use bash script?

Comment: You could. I won't be of much use though as BASH  scripting is not something I understand well enough for this task.

Comment: thanks @Adrian Klaver